# UEFI Linux Installation To External Flash Drive

Tags: linux, boot, usb-flash-drive, uefi

Recently I've bought myself a "Mini-PC" box that came with Windows 10. It only supports UEFI boot (no  BIOS). Eager to play with Linux Mint on the box, I've installed it in UEFI mode, making sure the bootloader is written to the USB drive during the installation. Booting into linux on the PC box works, since contrary to my choice, the "Linux" boot option was added to the UEFI partition of the box (and shows up every time I boot, even without the flash drive), but when I plug in the flash drive to my other computers, I'm unable to boot. All systems are running in 64-bit mode, and the PC box has a 64-bit UEFI.

Does anyone have any idea how to create a UEFI Linux Mint installation on a flash drive which will boot on multiple computers, just like it used to work on BIOS, or do I have to tweak the UEFI partitions of each of the computers I want to use with Linux? When you boot a live CD in UEFI mode, it works between multiple PCs without modifyng anything, so why can't I install Linux and boot it the same way, without modifying any of the local UEFI partitions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/978834/boot-from-usb-dvd-in-efi-mode

Comment: I suggest you to try this two software for making bootable USB for Linux: https://rufus.akeo.ie/      and  http://www.pendrivelinux.com/   I am sure both will satisfy your need.